# \DeclareCaptionType with accents

Tags: captions

When I try to create a new caption type with an accent on it, it gives an error:

```
\DeclareCaptionType{grafico} %ok
\DeclareCaptionType{gráfico} %error
```

I have this packages included:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Can someone tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: you can't with pdflatex. The name is used to create commands, and command names can contain accented glyphs with this engine. With lualatex it would work.

Comment: Probably `\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Gráfico]{grafico}` is an alternative.

Comment: AFAIK `\DeclareCaptionType` and `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` have exactly the same syntax so `\DeclareCaptionType[name=Gráfico]{grafico}` should work as well.